# Cant Rotate,Scale when I hook a vert on a curve in Blender 2.8

Tags: bezier-curves

Here's an little video how I used to be able to rotate and scale the curve using hooks in Blender 2.79

https://streamable.com/byura

Any Work around or fix would be highly appreciated!! :D

Answer (score 2):

I went into the same issue today in 2.8. The way to make it works is to select your BezierCurve handles in Edit Mode then press RMB and click on Set Handle Type -> Toggle Free/Align, now you can rotate and scale your Hook.

Comment: Had the same problem in Blender 3.3.1 and your solution still worked! Any idea what is actually causing the problem or why toggling Free/Align solves it?